# Elasticsearch sorting by array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a column **engagement** like this along with other columns

record 1

```
"date":"2017-11-23T06:46:04.358Z",
"remarks": "test1",
"engagement": [
    {
      "name": "comment_count",
      "value": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "like_count",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  ....
  ....
```

record 2

```
  "date":"2017-11-23T07:16:14.358Z",
  "remarks": "test2",
  "engagement": [
    {
    "name": "comment_count",
    "value": 3
    },
    {
    "name": "like_count",
    "value": 9
    }
  ],
  ....
  ....
```

I am storing objects in an array format, Now I want to sort the data by desc order of any given object name, e.g. value of like_count or value of share_count.

So if I sort by **like_count** then **2nd** record should come before the 1st record as the value of like_count of the **2nd** record is 9 compared to the value of like_count of the first record which is 2.

How to do this in elasticsearch?

Comment: Pfff, you'd be much better if you had a single field that would combine the value itself and the name and you'd do a sorting on that.

Comment: Do you have a known set of `name`s in there? For example, would be feasible to create a field called `like_count_value` that should contain a value like `9_like_count`?

Comment: I have multiple kinds of engagement values (e.g. share_count, followers, followings, reach etc)  so If I create columns then I will have to create new columns every time if a new engagement key comes. Current structure supports any kind of engagement value without creating a new column by just appending key/value in the array.

Comment: I understand what you say and I understand is way more comfortable like this :-). But, performance wise, you won't be better off with way.

Comment: I got something like this but it is not working as per expected.
{
  "_source": ["engagement"],
  "sort": {
    "engagement.value": {
      "order": "desc",
      "nested_filter": {
        "term": {
          "engagement.name": "like_count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Why it's not working as expected, because it should?

Comment: And `engagement` should be of type `nested`, I assumed you have it like that. But re-reading your post I don't see it mentioned anywhere. It SHOULD be `nested`. Something like this: `"engagement": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }`

Answer (score 3):

You should have something like the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": { 
      "path": "engagement",
      "filter": {
        ...somefilter...
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "engagement.name": { 
      "order": "desc",   
      "mode":  "min",   
      "nested_filter": { 
        ...same.filter.as.before
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Elastic Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html)